# Integral manipulations in section 114 of Berestetski, Lifshitz and Pitaevskii: Quantum Electrodynamics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, integration

I am working my way through section 114 [Radiative corrections to Coulomb's law] in Berestetski, Lifshitz and Pitaevskii: Quantum Electrodynamics. The authors consider the radiative correction $\delta \Phi$ of the potential of a static charge. Starting from the form of this correction in the momentum representation, the authors seek its form in the coordinate representation by means of the inverse Fourier transform, eq (114.3)
$$\delta\Phi(\mathbf{r})=\int e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} \delta\Phi(\mathbf{k}) d^3 k/(2\pi)^3$$
Since $\delta\Phi(\mathbf{k})$ is radial in the momentum vector $\mathbf{k}$ the authors introduce the variable substitution $t=-\mathbf{k}^2$ to arrive at
$$\delta\Phi(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^\infty\delta\Phi(t)\frac{\sin(r\sqrt{-t})}{r}d(-t)$$
Then the authors do a next step, and this is where I get lost. They introduce a second variable substitution $y=\sqrt{-t}$ and arrive at
$$\delta\Phi(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi^2 r} im \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\Phi(-y^2)e^{iry}ydy$$
They point out that in arriving at this expression they have used the fact that the integrand is an even function of $y$ and the aim of the exercise is to arrive at an integral referring only to the imaginary part of $\delta\Phi$ only since "these are given by integrals which do not involve divergences", as stated at the end of section 112, and which is realized by the final variable substitution $y=ix$. However, it is not clear to me how the authors through the variable substitution $t\rightarrow y$ obtained an expression involving only the imaginary part of an integral. Any clues ?

Comment: I think it's just something like 
\begin{align}
4\pi^2 r \delta\Phi(r)&=\int_0^\infty\delta\Phi(t)\sin(r\sqrt{-t})d(-t) \\
&=\int_0^\infty\delta\Phi(-y^2)\sin(r y)d(y^2) \\
&=\int_0^\infty\delta\Phi(-y^2)\sin(r y) y dy + \int_0^\infty\delta\Phi(-y^2)\sin(r y) y dy \\
&=\int_0^\infty\delta\Phi(-y^2)\sin(r y) y dy - \int_0^{-\infty} \delta\Phi(-y^2)\sin(r y) y dy \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta\Phi(-y^2)\sin(r y) y dy  \\
&=\mathrm{Im}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta\Phi(-y^2)e^{ir y} y dy  \\
\end{align}

Comment: In the final step you are, I believe, assuming that $\delta\Phi$ is real, whereas in fact the whole sequence of manipulations aims to express the integral in terms of the imaginary part of $\delta\Phi$.

Comment: Upon second thought, your manipulations are correct, because the radiative correction to the potential $\delta\Phi$ is real along the real line. The chosen final form of the integral is convenient, though, when evaluating it by contour integration similar to what is done here [https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/contour-integral-from-peskin-schroeder-intro-to-qft.830208/]